# Given an array with odd length, look at the first, last, and middle values in the array and return an array with those three values

Tags: java, arrays

So for any given odd length array, I need to look at the first, middle and last value, and return an array with only hose 3 values but in ascending order.This is what I have, but it's only working with arrays of 3 elements, it's not working for other odd length arrays:

```
public int[] maxTriple(int[] nums) {

  int toSwap, indexOfSmallest = 0;
    int i, j, smallest;

    for( i = 0; i < nums.length; i ++ )
    {               

        smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for( j = i; j < nums.length; j ++ )
        {
            if( nums[ j ] < smallest )
            {
                smallest = nums[ j ];
                indexOfSmallest = j;
            }                   
        }

        toSwap = nums[ i ];
        nums[ i ] = smallest;
        nums[ indexOfSmallest ] = toSwap;
    }

    return nums;
}
```

Comment: what is your issue that you are dealing with? do you get any error?

Comment: _it's not working well_ is not a very helpful information, what problem actually you are facing?

Comment: It works for arrays of 3 elements, but not for other odd length arrays

Comment: @ZurielDelC.it seems your for loops go through your array once? I guess? **one swap just be made that is all** what your array does include?

Comment: Provide some input/output for both successful and unsuccessful cases?

Comment: Successful cases:                                                                          maxTriple({0, 1, 2}) → {0, 1, 2}, my result: {0,1,2}                                 maxTriple({5, 2, 3}) → {2, 3, 5}, my result: {2,3,5}                      Unsuccessul cases:                                                                 maxTriple({1, 2, 3, 1, 1}) → {1, 1, 3}, my result: {1, 1, 1, 2, 3}   maxTriple({1, 7, 3, 1, 5}) → {1, 3, 5}, my result: {1, 1, 3, 5, 7}

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the sorted array, so if you need just the first, middle and last values you can try it like this:

```
public int[] maxTriple(int[] nums) {

      int toSwap, indexOfSmallest = 0;
        int i, j, smallest;

        for( i = 0; i < nums.length; i ++ )
        {               

            smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            for( j = i; j < nums.length; j ++ )
            {
                if( nums[ j ] < smallest )
                {
                    smallest = nums[ j ];
                    indexOfSmallest = j;
                }                   
            }

            toSwap = nums[ i ];
            nums[ i ] = smallest;
            nums[ indexOfSmallest ] = toSwap;
        }

        nums=new int[]{nums[0],nums[(nums.length/2)],nums[nums.length-1]};
        return nums;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this too hard.  If the length of your array is less than 3 or even, return null.

Otherwise, get the first element, the last element, and the middle element and store them in a new array.  Sort the array with `Arrays.sort()` and return the new array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxTriple(new int[] {1, 4, 2, 4})));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxTriple(new int[] {1, 4, 2, 4, 5})));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(maxTriple(new int[] {75, 99, 4, 999, 4, 65, 23})));
}

public static int[] maxTriple(int[] nums) {
    if (nums.length < 3 || nums.length % 2 == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    int[] result = new int[3];
    result[0] = nums[0]; // First
    result[1] = nums[nums.length - 1]; // Last
    result[2] = nums[nums.length / 2]; // Middle
    Arrays.sort(result);

    return result;
}
```

Results:

```
null
[1, 2, 5]
[23, 75, 999]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used another approach with ternary operators. I hope it can be useful...

```
public int maxTriple(int[] nums) {
    return (nums[0] > nums[nums.length/2]) ? (nums[0] > nums[nums.length-1] ? 
            nums[0] : nums[nums.length-1]) : (nums[nums.length/2] > nums[nums.length-1] 
                    ? nums[nums.length/2] : nums[nums.length-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:

```java
public int[] maxTriple(int[] nums) {
    int[] myArray = new int[3];
    int length = nums.length;
    int middle = nums[(length + 1) / 2 - 1];
    int last = nums[length - 1];
    int first = nums[0];

    myArray[0] = nums[0];
    myArray[1] = nums[middle];
    myArray[2] = nums[last];
    return myArray;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you are tyring to do is called [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). Here is the code for that:

```java
int[] maxTriple(int[] nums, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {
            if (nums[j] < nums[i]) {

                int toSwap = nums[i];
                nums[i] = nums[j];
                nums[j] = toSwap;
            }
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```